# BackGround App refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app i am using background app refresh. I've checked Background Fetch from Background modes. It refreshes data at background when I click on Simulate Background Fetch. But if my app is closed and i update data from server, my app doesn't update data. Even I was waiting for very long time(about an hour) and relaunch. Please help.
My code is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler 
{
    NSLog(@"Fetch Started");
    [self getDataAtBAckground];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    NSLog(@"Fetch completed"); 
}
```

And in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return YES;
}


-(void)getDataAtBAckground {

//-------Get All Categories-------//

expense = [[Expense alloc]init];

[expense deleteAllCategories];
[expense deleteAllChannels];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myServerAddress/categories.php"];
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    NSArray *post = [json valueForKey:@"post"];
    NSArray *categNameArray  = [post valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSArray *categImageArray = [post valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSArray *categIdArray    = [post valueForKey:@"id"];

    for(int counter=0; counter<[categNameArray count]; counter++)
    {
        [expense addCategoryWithName:[categNameArray objectAtIndex:counter] image:[categImageArray objectAtIndex:counter] Catid:[categIdArray objectAtIndex:counter]];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show `getDataAtBAckground`. Also, please report whether your logging takes place when app has been suspended.

Comment: Also please describe your testing procedure. You are on a device, yes? You are running your app independently of Xcode, yes?

Comment: When you say "if my app is closed" do you mean in the background or did you force it closed by double clicking the home button and swiping the app off the top of the screen? If you force an app closed background refresh will not happen.

Comment: @beyerss Very good point.

Comment: @matt I am testing on device independently of xcode.